# Keyword precedence in Spring Data method name

Tags: java, spring-data

This is the JPQL which I am forced to annotate:

```
@Query(
 "SELECT a from Employee a WHERE eid = :eid and hireDate between :first and :last order by projectId"
)
```

Because I am unable to get this to work:

```
public List<Employee>
findByEidAndHireDateBetweenOrderByProjectId(
  String eid, Date first, Date last);
```

Is my method name correctly following the naming convention of Spring Data query method name?

Answer (score 1):

> Static ordering can be applied by appending an OrderBy clause to the
>   query method referencing a property ***and providing a sorting direction***
>   (Asc or Desc).
>   [Spring Data JPA - Reference Documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-creation)

Possible issues:

- "findByid..." **<-** id is in lower case
- You mention that you want to search by "**eid**", so it should probably be "findByEid..."
- You don't specified order direction **<-** *This is probably the main problem*;

Repository:

```java
public interface EmployeeRepository extends
    PagingAndSortingRepository<Employee, Integer> {

    public List<Employee> findByEidAndHireDateBetweenOrderByProjectIdDesc(
        String eid, Date first, Date last);
}
```

Employee entity:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
public class Employee implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "employee_sequence", sequenceName = "employee_sequence",     allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "employee_sequence")
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "eid", nullable = false)
    private String eid;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "hire_date", nullable = false)
    private Date hireDate;

    @Column(name = "projectId", nullable = false)
    private Integer projectId;

    public Employee() {
    }

    // ...
    // Setters / Getters
    // ...

    // ...
    // eclipse generated hashCode / equals / toString
    // ...
}
```

This code works on my machine:

- Database: PostgreSQL
- ORM implementation: hibernate 4.1.9
- Spring: 3.2.0.RELEASE
- Spring-Data: 1.2.0.RELEASE

If you want to create a query method which will support dynamic sorting - [Spring Data JPA - 1.3.2.3. Special parameter handling](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.special-parameters)

Comment: Sorry for the typo - I did do findByEid... which was the method name that encountered the problem. I have corrected the typo.

Comment: What about providing a sorting direction in the method name?